# Add row of HTML table to another web page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've set up a web page to query a database based on a user search that returns database row values into an HTML table via PHP and jQuery. Next to each returned row sits a button that displays 'Add to wish list'. I'd like for this button to be able to add that given row to a table on another web page, and store it there whilst the user navigates and searches the database further, adding more rows to the new table if necessary.

I've looked into this and the best solution I've come up with so far seems to be utilising PHP to store a `$session` like shopping carts on web pages do. However most of the scripts on the web are far more complex than I'll need for this web page as it's not an e-commerce site.

Is there a simpler way to do this, perhaps in jQuery that on click of 'wishlist' simply appends the data from a row to an HTML table on another page in a similar fashion?

Comment: The simplest way is probably to have the button submit the row data to a php page which adds it to the user's session. When the user goes to wishlist.php, display the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can use **HTML5 WebStorage** supported by about 87% of browsers click to see browsers support here http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage. Otherwise you have to use PHP session or Database or something with Jquery as you said. You can follow this to learn basic about HTML 5 LocalStorage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Remember this feature only supports strings to save data. Use JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() to parse and save array if you want. You can use some code like this

```
//To set user's selected wishlist
var wishlistarray = [];
wishlistarray[0] = 'save data in whatever way you like';
localStorage["wishlist"] = JSON.stringify(wishlistarray);

//To get previously saved user's wishlist
var wishlistarray = JSON.parse(localStorage["wishlist"]);
```